# What does the word decker mean? How can I use it in a sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

According to this [dictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/decker) it has two meaning

1. Something having a deck or an indicated number of levels, stories, or tiers. Often used in
   combination. A three-decker apartment house; double-decker buses.
2. One who, or that which, decks or adorns; a coverer.

So Is the sentence below correct?

**These lights are decker and essential here.**

Comment: Maybe. Check the comments below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no. I see how a bit of decoration could be "that which decks or adorns," but be careful. Dictionaries work best when you go from the word to its meaning, rather than the other way: using the explanation they give to decide when to use a word. For instance, a textbook is "something that helps students learn," but you wouldn't call a teacher a "textbook." To help avoid these problems you have to look for a lot of examples of how the word is used to get a feel for it.

Some points:

1. Both uses of the word are fairly rare. As an affix, as in "double-decker," it's only used when something has more than one "deck," like a bus in London. There aren't many situations when you'd use this term, and usually you could use other wordings too if you wanted ("this bus has two levels").
2. The definition that "a decker is someone or something who 'decks'" is even more rare. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decker) doesn't even cover it. I honestly can't imagine ever using it in a useful sentence.
3. There *is* a good word for "an object that adorns something": a *decoration*. You could say "These lights are a decoration," or use the adjective "These lights are decorative."
4. But look up "decorative" in a dictionary for a full definition. One of the points is that it's the *opposite* of "essential." Something decorative is there for appearance only and is not an important functional part.

Comment: There is a frequent use in the UK where double-decker busses are common in most cities. One other use I've seen is when describing multi-layer sandwiches. And there are multi-decked cruise ships.

Comment: @PeterJennings Yup, those examples occurred to me and I'd still say it's "fairly rare." In fact, I'm dubious about the quoted example using it for apartment buildings!

Comment: A common short version of *decoration* is *decor*. You might say "These lights are decor."

Comment: I already know these two word: decorative and decoration. Recently learned a new verb "deck" and noun "decker" For example

1. She decked him with a hard slap.
2. "Deckers" killed Luchadors.

And this question got me that what does deckers even mean? (except just a nickname for cyberpunks) Is there any other way to use it in a sentence?

Comment: We have a word in Persian دکور کردن (decor kardan) that literally means to decorate. And دکور or دکوری (decor or decory) which means something that is decorated or something that is just for place beauty not for a special function. Or the background decoration of TV show and it's actors.

How do you define "decker" mean?

Comment: @PeterJennings - in the UK, 'busses' would be a typo for 'buses'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey   I know it's a name in that video game, but I'm interested in understanding its meaning. Why did they choose the name 'Deckers'? Is it because they knock people down or do they decorate something well-known?

Comment: @KavehBehnia I *strongly* urge you to throw away the notion of "decker" as a word of its own, especially meaning "one who adorns." 1) Even the word "deck" meaning "adorn" is very rare nowadays. It's mainly kept in modern consciousness by the Christmas song "Deck the Halls." You also see, somewhat less, the participle "decked" as in "She was all decked out in sequins and rhinestones."

Comment: @KavehBehnia 2) You can add "-er" or "-or" to just about any verb to mean "one who does that thing." If context supports it the meaning will be clear, but it doesn't make it a vocabulary word to learn. E.g. "At night the building was swarmed by an army of dusters, moppers, and Hooverers." The typical meaning of "duster" is a tool for dusting, so there's no need to memorize this specialized meaning of "one who dusts." 3) Please don't use comment sections to bring in new parts of a question. The comments under an answer are for talking about an answer, like what needs to be added to it. The...

Comment: ... The question of a name in a video game is completely separate from both "double-decker" and "one who adorns." (And if the question had been "what does that name mean," I suspect it would be off-topic on this site.) 4) Don't go looking too hard for meaning in proper names, and I encourage you to ignore the speculation in that fandom wiki. "Decker" is a name, not a common one, but more common than just the one video game. [It seems to come from](https://www.thebump.com/b/decker-baby-name) Hebrew origins, or perhaps occupations like ditch digger. (Note, baby-name websites are worse than...

Comment: ... fandom wikis for presenting speculation as truth. ;D But seriously, they're often the worst sorts of psuedo-etymology.)

Comment: There is another completely different meaning of the word deck. In BrE if you deck someone, you have knocked them over, usually in a fight, not adorned them with pretty things!

Comment: @PeterJennings The discussion has already wandered plenty from the original question; let's not encourage it! That meaning has been brought up already in this chat-as-comments.

Comment: @AndyBonner Man, even names have got meaning. We shouldn't leave the asking about them just because they're a name. Usually writers choose a name for a special reason.

Comment: I somewhat agree with your opinion regarding proper nouns. However, I don't agree that 'Decker' is a proper noun. To illustrate this, take the example of Luchadors who are lucha libre wrestlers @AndyBonner

Comment: @KavehBehnia Luchador also is a common noun, unless one particular wrestler uses it as a name. Basically, "name" is a handy litmus test for proper nouns: it's when we use a noun *as* a name or as a substitute for a name (like the common question on here: "Hey Dad"—substitute for a name, proper noun—vs "my dad"—common noun).